# Specialize function template result

Tags: c++, template-specialization, template-meta-programming

I'm pretty new to template metaprogramming and can't find my thinking error in this approach:

```
template <typename T>
    typename T::ReturnType Query(const std::string& Str);

template <>
ResultTypeRowCount Query(const std::string& Str) { return this->queryRowCount(Str); }
```

ResultTypeRowCount implements a public typedef with the name ReturnType

Thankyou for reading

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do here?  C++ won't deduce the return type of your function, since given just the arguments there's no way to deduce `T`.  What is your expected behavior here?

Comment: I want to archive some kind of return- type overloading. As I can't declare templates as virtual i map functions to specialisations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
template <>
ResultTypeRowCount::ReturnType Query<ResultTypeRowCount>(const std::string& Str) { return this->queryRowCount(Str); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Specializing your template should follow this pattern:

```
template<typename T>
  void foo() {
  }

template<>
  void foo<int>() {
  }
```

Comment: Right idea, except that your response glosses over one of the exact things that the questioner got wrong.

Comment: It's true. I only commented on the template metaprogramming concept being missed, which seemed the most relevant.  Learning to fish, and what not.